# Error al posicionar una foto

Tags: android, imagen

Estoy haciendo una app, y en tengo una pantalla donde tengo imagen predeterminada que puedo cambiar y texto debajo de esa imagen. Y aparte en otras un texto que Personalizo así como la imagen, dicha imagen se guarda bien con el nombre que personalizo pero se me posiciona en la primera imagen predeterminada, adjunto foto para mas explicación y mi código. En otras pantallas donde tengo todas las imagenes y textos que se pueden personalizar, me lo hace todo bien, pero aquí que tengo parte prederminadas y parte que se pueden personalizar me lo posiciona mal.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

El código:

```
if (TxTCasa != null) {
        db = new MySQLiteHelCasa(this);
        for (int x = 0; x < TxTCasa.length; x++) {
            txt = findViewById(TxTCasa[x]);
            boton = findViewById(CasaBoton[x]);
            try {
                lista = db.getTexpicCasa();
                t = lista.get(x);
                Btexto = boton.getText().toString();
                texto = null;
                texto = t.getTexto().trim();
                txtBoton = t.getBoton();
                txt.setText(texto);
                nomArchivo = texto;
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }

//Se cargan las imágenes de toda la pantalla (Imagino que aquí es donde está el problema)
    String palabra;
    for (int i = 0; i < CASILLAS.length; i++){
        try{
            txt = findViewById(TxTCasa[i]);
            texto = txt.getText().toString().trim();
            imgPictos = new File(getFilesDir(), nombreCarpeta + PICTOS[i]+".png");
            imgPictos2 = new File(getFilesDir(), nombreCarpeta + texto + ".png");
            Uri url = Uri.parse(urlpicto + PICTOS[i] + ".png");
            Uri url2 = Uri.parse(urlpicto + texto + ".png");
            if (imgPictos.exists()){
                imagen = findViewById(CASILLAS[i]);
                imagen.setImageURI(url);
            } else if (imgPictos2.exists()) {
                imagen = findViewById(CASILLAS[14+i]);
                imagen.setImageURI(url2);
            } else {
                BuscarClase buscarClase = new BuscarClase();
                palabra = PICTOS[i];
                buscarClase.diccionario(palabra);
                imagen = findViewById(CASILLAS[i]);
                int p = this.getResources().getIdentifier("drawable/" + palabra, null, this.getPackageName());
                if (p == 0) {
                    imagen.setImageResource(R.drawable.personaliza);
                } else {
                    imagen.setImageResource(p);
                }
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    imagen.setOnClickListener(v -> openGallery());
}

private void openGallery() {
    Intent gallery = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
    gallery.setType("image/*");
    if (gallery.resolveActivity(getPackageManager()) != null) {
        startActivityForResult(gallery, REQUEST_IMAGE_GET);
    }
}
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data){
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    if (resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK && data != null) {
        imageUri = data.getData();
        dir = new File(getFilesDir(), nombreCarpeta);

        if (!dir.exists()) {
            dir.mkdirs();
        }
        imagen.setImageURI(imageUri);
        imagen.buildDrawingCache();
        imgUri = imageUri.toString();
        cr= this.getContentResolver();
        try {
            bmap=android.provider.MediaStore.Images.Media.getBitmap(cr,imageUri);
        }catch(IOException ex){
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }
        guardarImagen(nomArchivo,bmap);
        dirImg = new File(getFilesDir(), nombreCarpeta + nomArchivo);
    }
}
private void guardarImagen(String nombre, Bitmap bmap){
    file = new File(dir,nombre );
    FileOutputStream fos;
    try{
        fos = new FileOutputStream(file);
        bmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 100, fos);
        fos.flush();
    } catch (IOException ex){
        ex.printStackTrace();
        Toast.makeText(contexto, "¡No se ha podido guardar la imagen!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
    file.getAbsolutePath();
}
//Aquí va a una BBDD SQLite para guardar el texto de los textviews personalizables
public void irCasa (View view){
    Intent i = new Intent(this, ModificaCasa.class);
    i.putExtra("botonPcasa", Btexto);
    i.putExtra("textocasa",texto);
    startActivityForResult(i,botonP);
}
//método para cambiar el texto de las imágenes con botón
public void onClick(View view){
    //Acciones de cada boton
    switch(view.getId()){
        case R.id.bcasa1:
            botonP = (15);
            Btexto = "Personalice1";
            if (texto== null){
                texto = "Personalizar";
            }else{
                txt = findViewById(R.id.textCasa1);
                texto = txt.getText().toString();
            }
            irCasa(view);
            txt.setText(texto);
            break;
        case R.id.bcasa2:
            botonP = (16);
            Btexto = "Personalice2";
            if (texto== null){
                texto = "Personalizar";
            }else{
                txt = findViewById(R.id.textCasa2);
                texto = txt.getText().toString();
            }
            irCasa(view);
            txt.setText(texto);
            break;
        case R.id.bcasa3:
            botonP = (17);
            Btexto = "Personalice3";
            if (texto== null){
                texto = "Personalizar";
            }else{
                txt = findViewById(R.id.textCasa3);
                texto = txt.getText().toString();
            }
            irCasa(view);
            txt.setText(texto);
            break;
        default:
            Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "Ningun valor", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
}
//Métodos para cambiar las imágenes que NO tienen botón
public void bater(View view){
    nomArchivo = "bater.png";
    img = R.drawable.bater;
    draw = new File(dir, nomArchivo);
    imagen = findViewById(R.id.bater);
    imagen.setOnClickListener(v -> openGallery());
}

public void basura(View view){
    nomArchivo = "basura.png";
    img = R.drawable.basura;
    draw = new File(dir, nomArchivo);
    imagen = findViewById(R.id.basura);
    imagen.setOnClickListener(v -> openGallery());
}
//Estos son los métodos para cambiar las imágenes que tienen botón
public void casa1(View view){
    nomArchivo = "casa1.png";
    txtI = findViewById(R.id.textCasa1);
    ImagenT= txtI.getText().toString();
    if (ImagenT.equals("")) {
        Toast.makeText(contexto, "¡Personalice el nombre primero!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }else{
        nomArchivo = ImagenT + ".png";
        img = R.drawable.agregarmas;
        draw = new File(dir, nomArchivo);
        imagen = findViewById(R.id.casa1);
        imagen.setOnClickListener(v -> openGallery());
    }
}

public void casa2(View view){
    nomArchivo = "casa2.png";
    txtI = findViewById(R.id.textCasa2);
    ImagenT= txtI.getText().toString();
    if (ImagenT.equals("")) {
        Toast.makeText(contexto, "¡Personalice el nombre primero!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }else{
        nomArchivo = ImagenT + ".png";
        img = R.drawable.agregarmas;
        draw = new File(dir, nomArchivo);
        imagen = findViewById(R.id.casa2);
        imagen.setOnClickListener(v -> openGallery());
    }
}
```

Comment: Y este es mi código:

Comment: Hola estaba leyendo tu pregunta, y siento que puedes cambiar de enfoque para mejorar tú código. Inicialmente que te parece usar databinding para reducir la solución ? Tu solución no esta mal, pero puedes mejorarla y reducir el codigo para que sea más sencillo darle un mantenimiento posterior. Para agregar databinding lo haces en tu archivo app gradle agregas esto: buildFeatures {  dataBinding true }

Comment: Soy novata en Android, pero miraré el tema del databinding, gracias

Comment: Con gusto estoy para ayudarte. Si me permites si tu app siempre va a tener el mismo número de imagenes por pantalla con databinding puedes reducir el código en cuanto a que ya no necesitarás hacer los llamados interminables findViewById...... Entonces puedes en una lista agregar todas las imagenes y asignarle los eventos correspondientes. Si crees que tu pantalla puede variar en la cantidad de imagenes podrias implementar un recyclerView. Con gusto te ayudo con algún ejemplo si necesitas.